# Live Vehicle tracking using J2ee

Tags: gps, tracking

I want to build a project on "Live Vehicle tracking system" using J2ee.following are my basic ideas-

1. a website from which end user can track the vehicle(tracking can be done on Google maps).
2. a GPS system embedded in the vehicle so that it can send location to the server.
3. i think of using J2ee.please suggest me whether to use this or any other language.

This is basic idea.please make correction if necessary.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

We are making sort of application using Spring ZK framework Maven and Mysql. Also we have our device for vehicle tracking. We already have some application made for tests. I can guarantee that J2ee is appropriate solution for it. We didn't have to made for example almost non of sql queries - all of them is easy to generate. We have experience in that field for 7 years and with different tools so yes that's good solution.